# Ipython-Spark setup for pyspark application

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark

I followed this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) to install Spark Standalone mode on a cluster by placing pre-built versions of spark on each node on the cluster and running `./sbin/start-master.sh` on Master and `./sbin/start-slave.sh <master-spark-URL>` on slave. How do I continue from there to setup a pyspark application, for example in ipython notebook to utilize the cluster? 
Do I need to install ipython on my local machine(laptop)?

Comment: I followed this blog post to set up ipython to work with pyspark. http://ramhiser.com/2015/02/01/configuring-ipython-notebook-support-for-pyspark/ If you are using python3 then there is a slight change you'll have to make, let me know if you are interested in that and I can dig it up from my machine. After following the above steps you can launch ipython like - ipython --profile=pyspark Also, you'll have to run pyspark directly on the cluster master. As of today, it is not possible to run pyspark remotely (e.g., from your laptop) for a standalone cluster.

Comment: thank you @quantum_random, does running ipython on the master automatically distributes the job across the workers?

Comment: No, by default it does not. You can use the --master option and specify the master url like spark://<master-url>:7077. This tells spark to use the entire cluster. Interestingly enough, I have not tried using ipython with the --master option so I don't know how well it works.

Answer (score 2):

To use ipython to run pyspark You'll need to set add the following environment variables in .bashrc

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython2 # As pyspark only works with python2 and not python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
```

This will cause `ipython2 notebook` to be launched when you execute `pyspark` from shell.

Note: I assume you already have `ipython notebook` installed. If not the easiest method is to use [Anaconda python](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/).

Reference:

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#using-the-shell
- http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/08/how-to-use-ipython-notebook-with-apache-spark/